# Copy one string to another until certain character in C

Tags: c, string

So, I'm creating a program in c, which works with files. I'm trying to get the string that the user typed until certain character. 
For example: the user typed test.txt, I would need the other variable to get all the text until the '.', so the other string would be test
I used strchr, but it gets the string after the point I need, is there any simple method to get the part before the dot?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 100

int main()
{
    char nome_arquivo[MAX];
    char conteudo[MAX];
    char *nome_backup;

    printf("Nome do arquivo que deseja realizar BACKUP com a extensao: ");
    fgets(nome_arquivo, MAX, stdin);

    //Sempre cuidar com o \n pois ele pode causar erros.
    strtok(nome_arquivo, "\n");

    FILE *arq = fopen(nome_arquivo, "r");

    rewind(arq);
    printf("\nMensagem dentro do arquivo:\n");

    while (fgets(conteudo, MAX, arq) != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n",conteudo);
    }

    nome_backup = strchr(nome_arquivo, '.');

    printf("%s\n", nome_backup);

    //FILE *arqbak = fopen(strcat(,".bak"),"w");

}
```

---

UPDATE:

```c
int main()
{
    char nome_arquivo[MAX];
    char conteudo[MAX];
    char *nome_backup;

    printf("Nome do arquivo que deseja realizar BACKUP com a extensao: ");
    fgets(nome_arquivo, MAX, stdin);

    //Sempre cuidar com o \n pois ele pode causar erros.
    strtok(nome_arquivo, "\n");

    FILE *arq = fopen(nome_arquivo, "r");

    rewind(arq);
    printf("\nMensagem dentro do arquivo:\n");

    while (fgets(conteudo, MAX, arq) != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n",conteudo);
    }

    nome_backup = strtok(nome_arquivo, '.');

    printf("%s\n", nome_backup);

    //FILE *arqbak = fopen(strcat(,".bak"),"w");

}
```

The ERROR is:
`Segmentantion fault (core dumped)`

Comment: You can use `strtok()`

Comment: Yep, but the '.' doesnt work for it

Comment: @Barmar I updated it, but it gives me an error when compiling

Comment: Please, tell us the *exact* error you're getting. We can't see your screen.

Comment: As always, before using a function incorrectly, [double-check the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok). If you pass `char` into a `char*` argument and you don't get a warning you need to turn on more warnings, like `-Wall`. Pay close attention that `strtok` *may* return `NULL` which will cause a crash if you go ahead and print it.

Comment: @tadman Updated!

Comment: As @tadman is suggesting, the second argument to `strtok` needs to be a `char*`, not a `char`.  You will want to change your code to `strtok(nome_arquivo, ".");`

Comment: You should also note that `strtok` will modify the original string (`nome_arquivo`) as it will replace the period with a NUL (`'\0'`).  You will need to use a different solution if you need to keep the original string around for later use.

Comment: ... please update the question with the latest code.

Answer (score 0):

HI you can you extract string upto "." and store it in different variable.

```
int main() {

//User input array
char nome_arquivo[MAX];
printf("enter the string:");
scanf("%s",&nome_arquivo);

//Required array
char name[MAX];

//copying string upto "."
for(int i=0; i<MAX; i++) 
{
if (nome_arquivo[i]==".")
break;
else
name[i]=nome_arquivo[i]);
}

// now name consists of your required string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making it very awkward on yourself. You are doing a good job in using `fgets()` to handle the input, but you do not need to tokenize the line of input to separate the filename and extension. Instead, (and instead of using `strchr()`), use `strrchr()` to locate the last `'.'` in the input string. That way if you have a filename that is similar to `"somefile.version.ext"` you can properly separate the filename into the name `"somefile.version"` and the extension `"ext"`.

`strrchr` will provide a pointer to the final `'.'` in the input (or `NULL` if there is no `'.'` included). There you have the address of the array filled by `fgets()` and you have the address of the final `'.'` in that string, all you need to do is subtract the pointer returned by `strrchr()` and the array filled by `fgets()` to determined the number of characters to copy. Then a simple call to `memcpy` is all you need to perform the copy and then *nul-terminate* the new string at that point.

For example, if you read with `fgets()` into `buf` and then want to separate `buf` into `fname` holding the filename and `ext` holding the extension, all you need is:

```
    char buf[MAXC], fname[MAXC], ext[MAXC], *p;
     ...
    if ((p = strrchr (buf, '.'))) {         /* get pointer to last '.' */
        memcpy (fname, buf, p - buf);       /* copy chars up to last '.' */
        fname[p-buf] = 0;                   /* nul-terminate fname */
        strcpy (ext, p+1);                  /* copy extension */
    }
```

Notice too, that since you have a pointer to the final `'.'`, all you need to do is `strcpy (ext, p+1);` to copy the extension.

A short example putting it altogether, and handling the case where there is no `'.'` in the filename could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 1024       /* if you need a constract, #define one (or moare) */ 

int main (void) {

    char buf[MAXC], fname[MAXC], ext[MAXC], *p;

    fputs ("enter filename: ", stdout);     /* prompt for filename */

    if (!fgets(buf, MAXC, stdin)) {         /* read/validate filename */
        fputs ("(user canceled input)\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    buf[strcspn (buf, "\n")] = 0;           /* trim \n from end of buf */

    if ((p = strrchr (buf, '.'))) {         /* get pointer to last '.' */
        memcpy (fname, buf, p - buf);       /* copy chars up to last '.' */
        fname[p-buf] = 0;                   /* nul-terminate fname */
        strcpy (ext, p+1);                  /* copy extension */
    }
    else {  /* no '.' in buf */
        strcpy (fname, buf);                /* copy bur to fname */
        *ext = 0;                           /* make ext empty-string */
    }

    printf ("filename  : %s\n", fname);
    if (*ext)
        printf ("extension : %s\n", ext);
}
```

(**note:** you should check that `fname` isn't the *empty-string* in order to handle dot-files, etc, `.somefile` -- that is left to you)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/filename_ext
enter filename: somefile.ext
filename  : somefile
extension : ext
```

What if there is more than one `'.'` in filename?

```
$ ./bin/filename_ext
enter filename: somefile.version.ext
filename  : somefile.version
extension : ext
```

What if there are none?

```
$ ./bin/filename_ext
enter filename: somefilenoext
filename  : somefilenoext
```

It is just a much simpler way to approach the separation rather than tokenizing the line. Look things over and let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `char *nome_backup`, the declaration should be `char* nome_backup`.

Comment: The declarations `char *nome_backup` and `char* nome_backup` are actually one and the same.

Comment: as well as ```char * nome_backup``` ;)